# Socket.io and android listview

Tags: android, listview, socket.io

I have an up and running socket.io services running on my server at somewhere , I have successfully established the connection between the server and android using socket.io documentation for android. now I need to implement a listview with realtime adapter. Can you please show me some snippet of the code that could iterate with server and listview through socket.io

Comment: Solved ! 
notifyitemchanged method on an adapter solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ! notifyItemChanged method on an adapter solved my problem.

```
adapter.notifyItemChanged();
```